# Nuitka error Cannot find ' ' in package ' ' as absolute import

Tags: python, nuitka

I'm trying to use the nuitka tool to turn my python program into executable on ubuntu.  It works fine if the program doesn't have any import statements but breaks when I use it on a program that imports something e.g.

test.py

```
import numpy

print "hello, world."
```

type this on commandline

```
nuitka --recurse-all --python-version=2.7 test.py
```

and gives me these errors

```
Nuitka:WARNING:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/numarray/functions.py:45: Cannot find 'copyreg' in package 'numpy.numarray' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/npy_pkg_config.py:11: Cannot find 'configparser' in package 'numpy.distutils' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1765: Cannot find 'Numeric' in package 'numpy.distutils' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1770: Cannot find 'numarray' in package 'numpy.distutils' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/f2py/diagnose.py:48: Cannot find 'numpy_distutils' in package 'numpy.f2py' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/f2py/diagnose.py:87: Cannot find 'numpy_distutils.command.build_flib' in package 'numpy.f2py' as absolute import.
```

Comment: I personally had this problem on Mac OS X, fresh install via pip. The build is also extremely slow

Comment: Maybe try setting the option --recurse-directory ?

Comment: Are you using virtualenv or any import mechanism where the imported moduels are not on PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @Hector all on PYTHONPATH. no virtualenv

Comment: Looks like [numpy is problematic](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2psa19/nuitka_a_python_compiler/)...  Is it just numpy or do other, simpler 3rd party packages have this issue?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about your particular use case but I also faced similar Cannot find '' in Package errors when using nuitka.

I was using sqlalchemy and had a similar issue with `configparser`.
After about a day of debugging I found out that Nuitka trips up with SWIG (Dynamically Loaded shared objects). 
What it means basically is, some programs/modules try to increase compatibility by using conditional imports.
For eg:

```
If python_version==3.5:
    import thislibrary
else:
    import thatlibrary
```

specifically the `configparser` library is named `configparser` in python3 and `ConfigParser` in python2.
So what basically is happening is that nuitka is trying to import python 3 stuff when you clearly are using python 2.

For me the fix was to modify the source code of sqlalchemy and change the `if else` construct to:

```
import thatlibrary
```

You can find more information in this [Guide](http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/2015/01/05/nuitka-compiler-for-python/#Issues_with_Dynamically_Loaded_shared_objects_SWIG)
 written by Tom Sheffler

Comment: I didn't use conditional imports and received this error. I'm considering placing a bounty on this question now.

Answer (score 2):

[Official answer from Nuitaka.](http://nuitka.net/posts/nuitka-release-0520.html)

What problem you facing same like another problem one user facing `package 'matplotlib' as absolute import.` this problem, then there nuitaka given comments below check if it useful for below comment.

> I think you might be using 32 bits Python on Windows and hit the 2GB RAM boundary. Use 64 bits for better luck. Incidentally I am working on scalability improvements for the next releases which ought to make this not happen. For now Nuitka loads all say 1000 modules into RAM and compiles them all globally. Needs a lot of RAM.